# Flink and Cassandra deployment similar to Spark?

Tags: cassandra, apache-flink

DataStax bundles Spark directly into it's DSE and most documentation I've seen recommends **co-locating Spark with each Cassandra node**, so that the spark-cassandra-connector works most efficiently with the data of that node.

Does Flink's Cassandra connector optimize it's data access based on Cassandra partition key hashes as well?  If so, does Flink recommend a similar co-located install of Flink and C* on the same nodes?